# Web-based wireless login: remember password

Tags: macos, wifi, password, login

When connecting to some wireless networks, the first webpage that I try to load redirects to a login screen.  It becomes possible to access the internet only after logging in.  I'm sure most people here are familiar with the situation.

It seems that OS X is smart about this and it brings up this login screen in a separate window as soon as I connect to the wireless network.  I don't need to open a browser and log in separately.  The system show me the login page as soon as I connect to the network, which is quite convenient.

Question: is it possible to coerce this special window to remember the username and password, like browsers are able to?

Comment: Thoses are called captive networks / portals : http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45418/how-to-automatically-login-to-captive-portals-on-os-x

Answer (score 1):

The special window is an instance of Safari, just without all the navigation bits.

Why don't you try copy-pasting the URL of the login screen to your browser, typing in your password, and telling safari you want to save it when it asks?

Comment: This sounds very reasonable but unfortunately it doesn't actually work.  While Safari does remember the password and offers to fill it, the auto pop up window does not.  I guess this is just a limitation to live with.

Comment: Well, logic was worth a shot. Sorry!