# Captive Portal in Mavericks

Tags: macos, wifi, web-browser

I connected to a public wifi hotspot with my MacBook AIr (Mavericks) and a login window appeared. I can't recall if I first tried to navigate to a website or not. I am familiar with logging into hotspots, where the login details appear in the browser itself. In this case, however, the login details appeared in a separate window (program?).

When I selected the browser, the global menu indicated "Firefox". When I selected the login window, the menu showed "Finder". Is this a (Apple?) [captive portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) program? It's the first time I've seen it on any OS platform.

Comment: see this answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/74473/46541

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's something built in the system . Sometimes it's able to detect a captive portal and it displays it in a separate window.

As @George Garside pointed out, it's a separate program located at `/System/Library/CoreServices/Captive Network Assistant.app`.

Also, if you have a iDevice you'll see a similar feature.

Comment: It **is** a separate program: /System/Library/CoreServices/Captive Network Assistant.app