# Any details about the captive/public wifi login screen browser?

Tags: wifi, safari

Is it just controlled by Safari's data. cookies, etc. somehow?  I'd think not since that'd be a major security hole.

In any case, are there any tools for deleting the cookies from the browser used by the captive/public wifi login screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use following to prevent Captive networks

Change: File Name

```
Captive network assistant
```

to

```
No More captive network assistant
```

in System/Library/CoreServices

Make note of this so you can change it back one day if you need to.

This will not delete cookies you already have but will stop getting more of them.

Comment: I now see the answer here too : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45418/how-to-automatically-login-to-captive-portals-on-os-x  Apparently 'Captive Network Assistant.app' actually doesn't save any cookies. Yey!  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3308224?start=15&tstart=0  I'd imagine one must change one's MAC address to do most things that one might wish to do by deleting cookies.