# Why am I seeing captive portal requests on my home network?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, airport

I have suddenly started getting prompts on my 2014 Mavericks MBP (10.9.5) every five minutes that bring up a page with HTML like the following:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Success</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>Success</BODY></HTML>
```

At the bottom of this modal window is a url:

```
http://www.apple.com/library/test/success.html
```

I am on my home network which uses an Airport Extreme running 7.6.4.  I did not make any known configuration changes to either my computer or my network.  Why am I suddenly seeing this page, which other posts suggest is a captive portal test?

I saw [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45418/how-to-automatically-login-to-captive-portals-on-os-x?lq=1) that demonstrated how to disable the Captive Network Assistant, but as I do take my computer to hotels that use these portals, I'm reluctant to jump straight to that.  Instead, is there something on my Airport that is generating/blocking these all of a sudden and it shouldn't be?  I tried a factory reset of the Airport and I'm still seeing this issue.

How can I configure my network so I stop getting these annoying popups?

Comment: Seems like the only common denominator is Mac OS 10.9.5 - only users in our office with 10.9.5 see it, haven't updated any other software.

Comment: I noticed this just now too. I think apple broke something, that URL is returning the HTML as entity encoded ie "&lt;HTML&gt;&lt;HEAD&gt;&lt;TITLE&gt;Success&lt;/TITLE&gt;&lt;/HEAD&gt;&lt;BODY&gt;Success&lt;/BODY&gt;&lt;/HTML&gt;"

This is broken on my friends' iPhone 4 running iOS 6.something, I got around the problem by turning off "auto-login"

Comment: I have raised a bug with apple (I have a developer account), with bug number: 21832176.  Hopefully they fix it soon.

Comment: I have the same issue: OS X 10.9.5 . No update was installed by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [page](http://www.apple.com/library/test/success.html) has now been corrected, which should mean that the popup no longer occurs.

Comment: So there was an error on the test page that was causing this?

Comment: Amazingly enough, that's my conclusion. Have to say, this seems like a rather unstable implementation, but hey, what do I know... I'm only a web dev!

Comment: Yes, there was an error on the apple page, I finally got a response from Apple Developer Relations and they told me "Can you please verify and see if this issue still happening?  We have changed something server side.".  Obviously they fixed it a long time ago now.