# Why is my computer making hundreds of requests to captive.apple.com?

Tags: network, catalina, dns, privacy

I'm experimenting with [NextDNS](https://nextdns.io), and I noticed that my PC is making hundreds of requests an hour to `captive.apple.com`. Currently 40% of my DNS queries are to apple.com.

I understand this is a feature to detect if the computer is connected to a captive portal. However, it's not connected to a captive portal, it's connected to my home network and DNS requests, including requests to `captive.apple.com` are resolving.

Even if I connect to a VPN that has its own DNS settings, the OS continues to send these `captive.apple.com` requests to the DNS server specified in the Network preferences (although other requests go via the VPN).

I tried disabling `com.apple.captive.control` from [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/140843/74912), however the requests are still being sent. I disabled my network connection for a while to confirm my computer was the source of the requests, and the requests stopped appearing in the logs. They reappeared again when I re-enabled my connection.

NextDNS has a quota, and these DNS requests are going to use the majority of the quota.

Why is my computer making so many requests to `captive.apple.com`, is it normal, and is there a way to stop it?

I'm on OSX 10.15.7.

Comment: Just a guess but what is the order of network connections you're using?  I'm just wondering if you have a captivate network before your home network.

Comment: I'm only connected to a single Wifi network.

Comment: Not 'connected' but the order of preference.  I see you've figured it out so that's good.

Comment: Yeah, it was first preference. But anyway, conclusion is I need a better-behaved VPN client. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I analysed the traffic with `tcpdump -k port 53` (suggested by [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/euopzp/strange_dns_queries_from_macbook/)), and it turns out it was `expressvpnd`, part of Express VPN.

That was surprising, because I didn't have Express VPN client running, but it appears to set up a demon that sends DNS queries to `captive.apple.com` and `www.mb6gpu84.com` even when the app is not running.

I removed `expressvpnd` and killed the process, and the requests stopped.